# Setting title for checkbox in primefaces datatable with multiple selection column

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, accessibility

I want to set titles for checkboxes in a primefaces datatable with a multiple selection column. As an example I use a snippet of the primefaces showcase (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml).

```
<p:dataTable id="checkboxDT" var="car" value="#{dtSelectionView.cars6}" selection="#{dtSelectionView.selectedCars}" rowKey="#{car.id}" style="margin-bottom:0">
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
</p:dataTable>
```

The column in this table is filled with generated checkboxes and I wonder if there is a (declarative) way to set the titles of these checkboxes (for example: select item #itemName).
I need the titles for reasons of accessibility, so that a screenreader user knows which element is selected.

Thx in advance!

Comment: Not sure if I got you right, you want to display the name of the selected item? ..next to / above the line? Or just a label at the 'select all' option in the column header?

Comment: I want to set the title-attribute of the generated checkboxes. So that a tooltip is displayed when you hover over the checkboxes.

Comment: Check the primefaces tooltip: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/tooltip/tooltipOptions.xhtml#
Set an id on your `<p:column>` and point to it in your tooltip.

Comment: This is a good idea and it would work nicely for plain tooltipping. But the problem I am facing is making the checkboxes accessible to screen reader users. The primefaces tooltip is located by absolute positioning and overlay, but not directly associated to the checkbox. So the screenreader won't find it when selecting a checkbox element.