# Setting tooltip for checkbox in primefaces datatable

Tags: java, primefaces

Hi there I want to set tooltip for selection column in primfaces datatable.As an example I used the following code.

```
  <p:dataTable id="checkboxDT" var="car" value="#{dtSelectionView.cars6}" 
   selection="#{dtSelectionView.selectedCars}" rowKey="#{car.id}" 
    style="margin-bottom:0">

    <p:column id="selectId" selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center">
        <p:tooltip for="selectId" value="tooltip for selection"/> 
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText id="textId" value="#{car.id}" />
        <p:tooltip for="textId" value="tooltip for text"/> 
    </p:column>


</p:dataTable>
```

In the above code tooltip is generated for text but not for selection.Already similar question is being asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489916/setting-title-for-checkbox-in-primefaces-datatable-with-multiple-selection-colum?newreg=48168ecf1a9d465abda4b83f894b22fd) but the solution mentioned in the comment is not working.
Please help me here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<p:column>` does not render `id` when `selectionMode="multiple"`.

A typical `<p:column selectionMode="multiple">` will render the following html:

```
<td class="ui-selection-column" role="gridcell">
    <span class="ui-column-title"></span>
    <div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
        <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
            <input name="form:dataTableId_checkbox" aria-checked="false" aria-label="" type="checkbox">
        </div>
        <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
            <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank ui-c"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Given the above codes, the tooltip cannot find the id to attach the value message.

In order to display your tooltip message for the selection column, you can use [PrimeFaces Selector API](https://www.primefaces.org/jquery-selector-api-meets-jsf/)

**Sample Code:**

```
<p:dataTable id="checkboxDT" var="car"
    value="#{dtSelectionView.cars6}"
    selection="#{dtSelectionView.selectedCars}" rowKey="#{car.id}"
    style="margin-bottom:0" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">

    <p:column selectionMode="multiple"
        style="width:16px;text-align:center">
        <p:tooltip for="@(.ui-datatable tr[role=row][data-ri=#{rowIndex}] td[class=ui-selection-column] div[class~=ui-chkbox])" value="tooltip for selection" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

This sample displays tooltip message when the mouse hovers the row checkbox.
You can play with this to achieve what you want.